# Adding a new variable based on different dates in r

Tags: r

I have a big dataset including the variable "ID", "Date", "AS", "Value", "Condition Day 1", "Condition Day 2", and "measurement".

We measured amino acids in different subjects (ID) on two different dates (Date) with two different conditions (Condition Day 1 and 2). There are two measurements on every date.

| ID | Date | AS | Value | Condition Day 1 | Condition Day 2 | measurement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015-07-12 | TRP | 23 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2015-07-12 | TRP | 11 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2015-07-12 | LEU | .. | 1 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 2015-07-12 | LEU |  | 1 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 2015-07-12 | .. |  | 1 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 2015-08-23 | TRP |  | 2 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 2015-08-23 | TRP |  | 2 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 2015-08-23 | LEU |  | 2 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 2015-08-23 | LEU |  | 2 | 1 |  |
| ... | ... | ... |  | 2 | 1 |  |
| 2 | .. | .. | ... | . |  |  |
| 2 | .. | ... | ... | .. . |  |  |

Now I am trying to create a new date variable based on the old one. The first date should be assigned the value "1", the second date the value "2". The problem I have, is that the dates change from ID to ID, since  every subject was tested on a different dates ranging from 2015 to 2018.

In the next step I want to create a new variable based on condition, and measurement ranging from 1 to 4.

```
"1" = measurement 1 + Condition 1 
"2" = measurement 2 + Condition 1
"3" = measurement 1 + Condition 2
"4" = measurement 2 + Condition 2
```

In the end the table should be looking something like this:

| ID | AS | Value | D_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRP | 23 | 1 |
| 1 | TRP | 11 | 2 |
| 1 | TRP | ... | 3 |
| 1 | TRP | ... | 4 |
| 1 | LEU | .. | 1 |
| 1 | LEU | ... | 2 |
| 1 | LEU | ... | 3 |
| 1 | LEU | ... | 4 |
| 2 | ... | ... | ... |
| 2 | ... | ... | ... |

I am kind of stuck here, especially with the first question. Can anyone help? Thank you so much!

*** UPDATE - MRE ***
here some example data

```
df = data.frame(ID=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
Date=c("2015-07-15", "2015-07-15", "2015-07-30", "2015-07-30", "2016-07-15", "2016-07-15", "2016-07-30", "2016-07-30"),
AS = c("TRP", "TRP", "TRP", "TRP", "ILE", "ILE", "ILE", "ILE"), 
Concentration = c(3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0),
Method_Day1 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1),
Method_Day2 = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), 
Sample = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2))
```

Comment: Hi Mats! It would be great if you can share a MRE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Questions with a MRE have good answers and make it easy for those who want to help you to give a quick answer.

Comment: The problem in a nutshell: how to assign two varying dates of every ID to a new variable with the level "1" and "2"; 1 being the older, 2 the newer date. I can't provide a MRE, at the moment I have no idea where to start.

Comment: You might be looking for something along the lines of `df %>% group_by(ID, AS) %>% dplyr::mutate(Date_encoding = case_when(Date == min(Date) ~ 1, d == max(Date) ~ 2, TRUE~0))`, but as pointed out this would be easier if you could provide some example data, e.g. for two example IDs, as an MRE (`dput(df)`.

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for the help so far. I provide some example data. The main goal is to assign for the two dates of each ID either a 1 or a 2. The problem is, that I have 40 IDs and all of them have two different dates, which means you cannot use the dates explicitly in the code. I hope I can get the message across. In the next step I want to create a new variable as pointed out in the question.

Comment: @Mats I've added an answer for that specific part of the question. This should work for an arbitrary number of IDs, because the Dates are only compared within each group.

Answer (score 1):

In order to encode the first and second date per ID, we can group by ID, and then compare each date against the groupwise max/min.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    date_encoding = case_when(
      Date == min(Date) ~ 1,
      Date == max(Date) ~ 2, 
      TRUE~0))
df1
# A tibble: 8 x 8
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID Date       AS    Concentration Method_Day1 Method_Day2 Sample date_encoding
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>         <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1 2015-07-15 TRP               3           1           2      1           1
2     1 2015-07-15 TRP               2           1           2      2           1
3     1 2015-07-30 TRP               1           2           1      1           2
4     1 2015-07-30 TRP               3           2           1      2           2
5     2 2016-07-15 ILE               3           2           1      1           1
6     2 2016-07-15 ILE               2           2           1      2           1
7     2 2016-07-30 ILE               1           1           2      1           2
8     2 2016-07-30 ILE               0           1           2      2           2
```

For the second part of your question, you can again use `mutate` and `case_when` based on the other column conditions, but the description you provide for Condition/Method Day 1/2 is not completely clear from the question.

**EDIT:** as this works only for the specific case of expecting exactly two Dates per ID, I'll also add the more general solution that will work for an arbitrary number of Dates per ID:

```
# sort and index Dates per ID
df %>% 
  dplyr::distinct(ID, Date) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(Date, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(encoding2 = row_number()) %>%
# then join them back to the original dataframe
  right_join(df, by = c("ID", "Date")) 
# A tibble: 8 x 8
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID Date       encoding2 AS    Concentration Method_Day1 Method_Day2 Sample
  <dbl> <chr>          <int> <chr>         <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 2015-07-15         1 TRP               3           1           2      1
2     1 2015-07-15         1 TRP               2           1           2      2
3     1 2015-07-30         2 TRP               1           2           1      1
4     1 2015-07-30         2 TRP               3           2           1      2
5     2 2016-07-15         1 ILE               3           2           1      1
6     2 2016-07-15         1 ILE               2           2           1      2
7     2 2016-07-30         2 ILE               1           1           2      1
8     2 2016-07-30         2 ILE               0           1           2      2
```